# MSVC: how to include the # character in the value of a pre-processor macro passed from the command-line

Tags: visual-c++, c-preprocessor

We build/run our embedded C code on MSVC as a convenient development/test environment.

Like most C compilers, MSVC allows the use of `-D`  to define pre-processor macros on the command line, i.e. `CL -DTHING=somechars somefile.c` will cause `somefile.c` to see `#define THING somechars`.  Our problem is that we need to pass in a pre-processor macro where the value contains the `#` character (it is used in a password that we are testing our embedded C code with and so has to be built into the embedded test code, we're stuck with it), i.e. we want to do `CL -DTHING=1234# somefile.c` so that `somefile.c` sees `#define THING 1234#`.

However [MSVC uses `#` as a substitute for `=`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/d-preprocessor-definitions?view=msvc-170), and so what `somefile.c` ends up seeing is `#define THING 1234=`; our password is now wrong.

Does anyone know if there's a way to stop MSVC doing this!?

I've tried escaping the value by putting `##` instead of `#` but that comes out as `=#`, which is not much better; I guess MSVC realizes there can't be two `=` signs but my string is still wrong and there's nothing sensible I can do in the embedded C code to recover the situation as this needs to be a `const`.

Comment: Have you tried using quotation marks, like `-DTHING="1234#"`?

Comment: Makes no different unfortunately; it strips the quotes and the outcome is the same.

Comment: Meh. Just thinking on the hoof. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `#` instead of `=` to separate the preprocessing symbol from its value when defining it via a command line. For example, this

```
CL /D THING#1234# somefile.c
```

will be converted to:

```c
#define THING 1234#
```

Or, in case the `THING` macro must expand to a proper (quoted) string literal, use the following format (note that quotes must be escaped with `\` on the command line to prevent being swallowed up):

```
CL /D THING#\"1234#\" somefile.c
```

This will be converted to:

```c
#define THING "1234#"
```

Comment: Aha, of course, I should have thought of that!  Thank you!